# mvc authentication with multiple roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I am building a mvc application with owin authentication. I am storing both users and admins in one table(Users). The application works in a way where the admin can also be an user(different views for admin vs user).

I am thinking the following options but i am not if it is correct approach

1. Once the admin logs in ask them if they want to use the application as an user or admin and redirect them based on that
2. Have two records one as an user and another as an admin (only if nothing else works)

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Umm... yes.  Use roles.  OWIN authentication can be used with the ASP.NET Identity model, which supports roles.

Answer (score 0):

The admin user by default is a privileged user, hence he should by default be shown admin pages. Similarly for the user.

However, as you mentioned, we can have a preview link which can render the page in a user mode if admin opts to.

Also, have a page where we can add / remove the roles for any user by the admin.

You may also have a user setting persisted in db to know the user's default view preference.